# MySQL where clause with null values

Tags: mysql, null, left-join, where-clause

I have this sql statement which looks like this:

```
SELECT hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer, adresse.adresse , poststed.poststed, land.navn, kontaktdata.epostadresse
FROM hovedenhet 
LEFT JOIN adresse on hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer = adresse.organisasjonsnummer
LEFT JOIN poststed on poststed.poststed_id=adresse.poststed_id
LEFT JOIN land on land.land_id = adresse.land_id
LEFT JOIN kontaktdata on kontaktdata.organisasjonsnummer = hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer
#where (adresse.adresseType=1)
```

I want to include rows even though some of the values are null and this works fine with this code, but when i uncomment the where clause it doesnt include the null columns anymore. I have tried to do where (adresse.adresseType = 1 or adresse =null) but it had no effect. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You should us "is NULL" not "=NULL"

Comment: That was probably the cause yes. It is working now by using "AND postadresse_adresse.adresseType=1" on the left join clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer, adresse.adresse , poststed.poststed, land.navn, kontaktdata.epostadresse
FROM hovedenhet 
LEFT JOIN adresse on hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer = adresse.organisasjonsnummer
LEFT JOIN poststed on poststed.poststed_id=adresse.poststed_id
LEFT JOIN land on land.land_id = adresse.land_id
LEFT JOIN kontaktdata on kontaktdata.organisasjonsnummer = hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer
where (adresse.adresseType = 1 or adresse.adresseType is null)
```

Comment: This is incorrect! NULL=NULL expression returns NULL, not true. You should use (adresse.adresseType is NULL)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I figured it out and are doing it this way right now:
LEFT JOIN adresse postadresse_adresse ON hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer = postadresse_adresse.organisasjonsnummer AND postadresse_adresse.adresseType=1

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
where (adresse.adresseType = 1 or adresse is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently using:

```
   SELECT hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer, adresse.adresse , poststed.poststed, 
    land.navn, kontaktdata.epostadresse
    FROM hovedenhet 
    LEFT JOIN adresse on hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer = adresse.organisasjonsnummer 
AND adresse.adresseType=1
    LEFT JOIN poststed on poststed.poststed_id=adresse.poststed_id
    LEFT JOIN land on land.land_id = adresse.land_id
    LEFT JOIN kontaktdata on kontaktdata.organisasjonsnummer = hovedenhet.organisasjonsnummer
```

Thanks for the answers!